# how to remove an item from a list with a click event in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var FilterList = React.createClass({
  remove: function(item){

    this.props.items = this.props.items.filter(function(itm){
      return item.id !== itm.id;
    });

    return false;
  },
  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(item) {
      return (
        <li>
          <span>{item}</span>
          <a href data-id="{item.id}" class="remove-filter" onClick={this.remove.bind(item)}>remove</a>
        </li>

      );
    };
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem.bind(this))}</ul>;
  }
});
var FilterApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [], item: {
      id: 0,
      type: null
    }};
  },
  onChangeType: function(e){
    this.setState({
      item: {
        id: this.state.items[this.state.items.length],
        type: e.target.value
      }
    });
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([this.state.item]);
    var item = {};
    this.setState({items: nextItems, item: {}});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Filters</h3>
        <FilterList items={this.state.items} />

        <form className="filter" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Filter</legend>
            <div className="form-grp">
              <select name="type" onChange={this.onChangeType}>
                <option>foo</option>
                <option>bar</option>
                <option>baz</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div className="actions">
            <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<FilterApp />, document.body);
```

I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to remove an item from the list. Probably making a ton of other bad design decisions here too, newbs.

Answer (score 7):

Props on components are immutable, meaning you cannot modify them directly. In your above example if the `FilterList` component wants to remove an item, it would need to call a callback from the parent component.

A simplified [example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/CptLemming/mjL2xuz8/).

`FilterApp` passes a remove function to `FilterList` that is called on the `onClick` event. This will remove an item from the parent, update the state, then cause `FilterList` to re-render with the new content.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this - I spent so long trying to work this out, your example lays it all out nice and clearly!

Comment: Man thank you for the simple example, helped me in react native

Answer (score 3):

Something like the below should work. Let your root component manage state.

```
var FilterList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(item) {
      return (
        <li>
          <span>{item}</span>
          <a href data-id="{item.id}" class="remove-filter" onClick={this.props.remove.bind(item)}>remove</a>
        </li>

      );
    };
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem.bind(this))}</ul>;
  }
});

var FilterApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [], item: {
      id: 0,
      type: null
    }};
  },
  onChangeType: function(e){
    this.setState({
      item: {
        id: this.state.items[this.state.items.length],
        type: e.target.value
      }
    });
  },
  remove: function(item, ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    var items = this.state.items.filter(function(itm){
      return item.id !== itm.id;
    });

    this.setState({ items: items });
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([this.state.item]);
    var item = {};
    this.setState({items: nextItems, item: {}});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Filters</h3>
        <FilterList remove={this.remove} items={this.state.items} />

        <form className="filter" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Filter</legend>
            <div className="form-grp">
              <select name="type" onChange={this.onChangeType}>
                <option>foo</option>
                <option>bar</option>
                <option>baz</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div className="actions">
            <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<FilterApp />, document.body);
```