# Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.; key prop already added in li

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am getting this warning after already adding the `key` prop to the `li` items in `TodoItems`:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `TodoItems`

I have the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>todo-list</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.0.0-beta.3/react-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fixed-data-table/0.6.3/fixed-data-table.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fixed-data-table/0.6.3/fixed-data-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <head>


        <body>
            <div style="margin-bottom: 35px">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/clock">clock</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/counter">counter</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/data-table-basic">data-table-basic</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/query-params-react-router">query-params-react-router</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/todo-list">todo-list</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/validated-form">validated-form</a>
            </div>


            <p>
                <a href="https://www.kirupa.com/react/simple_todo_app_react.htm" target="_blank">The tutorial link</a>
            </p>

            <div id="entry"></div>


            <script>
                function determineMode(filepath) {
                    var modeString = "ace/mode/" + filepath;
                    return modeString;
                }
            </script>

            <script src="/static/ace-builds2/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

            <script>
                var editor = ace.edit("editor");
                editor.getSession().setMode(determineMode('html'));
                editor.session.setNewLineMode("unix");
                editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
                editor.setFontSize(15);
            </script>

            <script type="text/babel">
                var destination = document.querySelector("#entry"); var TodoItems = React.createClass({ createTasks: function(item){ return this.props.entries.map(item => { return (
                <li data-bind-thisthing={item.key} key={item.key}>
                    <span>{item.text + " "} </span>
                    <a href="#" data-id="{item.id}" className="remove-filter" onClick={()=> this.props.remove(item)}
                        >
                            remove
                        </a>
                </li>
                ) }); }, render: function(){ return (
                <ul className="theList">
                    {this.createTasks()}
                </ul>
                ); } }); var TodoList = React.createClass({ getInitialState: function(){ return { items: [ 'If user clicks add button and input is empty, set a red border and focus the input box', 'Allow interactive DOM update of component when user edits code box', 'Allow categories for things like angular2, knockout, etc', 'Allow user to save new code snippets after starting in a sandbox', ] }; }, addItem: function(e) { var itemArray = this.state.items; if (this._inputElement.value.length > 0){ itemArray.push( { text: this._inputElement.value, key: this.state.items.length } ); this._inputElement.value = ""; this.setState({ items: itemArray }) } e.preventDefault(); }, // removing items from a list // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817241/how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-list-with-a-click-event-in-reactjs removeItem: function(item){ var items = this.state.items.filter(function(itm){ return item.key !== itm.key; }); this.setState({ items: items }); }, render: function() { return (
                <div className="todoListMain">
                    <div className="header">
                        <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                            <input ref={(a)=> this._inputElement = a} placeholder="enter task" />
                            <button type="submit">add</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <TodoItems remove={this.removeItem} entries={this.state.items} />
                </div>
                ); } }); ReactDOM.render(
                <div>
                    <TodoList/>
                </div>, destination );

            </script>
        </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Weird issues normally seem like `this` scope problems.

Comment: Initially `items` contains strings. They have neither `text` nor `key` property. That is why you see warning about duplicate keys and "undefined" as the output. BTW since user can remove elements you can't use array length at the time you add item as unique key.

Comment: Not sure but I guess `keys` are used by react to query virtual dom. So elements are added by loops, you are binding same structure multiple times. Hence you need add `key` so react can differentiate between them

Comment: Check the key is duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is initial state of TodoList.
**createTasks** function is expecting **entries** (props) an array containing objects where each object should have keys **id**, **text** and **key** but its getting array containing strings.